# Шаблон страницы товара в зависимости от категории WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Возможно вопрос глупый и все знают на него ответ, но работающего способа  найти не смог.

Задача:

Для товаров в нескольких категориях товара (в моём случае 3-х) мне необходимо отобразить страницу товара, отличающуюся от стандартной.

Насколько я понял, мне необходимо выяснить из какой категории товаров находится товар и использовать нужный шаблон для формирования страницы.

Я руководствовался [данным способом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789472/woocommerce-how-to-create-multiple-single-product-template-based-on-category/25797963#25797963), но результатов это не даёт.

Я использую шаблон [WP Bootstrap Starter](https://ru.wordpress.org/themes/wp-bootstrap-starter/)

Подскажите, как Вы решаете подобные задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данную задачу решил так

Для работы следующего кода, проследите, чтобы в папке *Ваша_тема*/woocommerce/ находился файл шаблона, в данном случае - это 'content-single-product-test.php'

Код размещается в файле functions.php Вашей темы.

```
    add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', 'custom_wc_template_part', 10, 3 );
function custom_wc_template_part( $template, $slug, $name ) {

// Название Вашего шаблона для страницы товара
$custom_template_name = 'content-single-product-test.php';

// В конструкции has_term( 'test', 'product_cat' ), необходимо заменить 'test' на ярлык нужной категории товара 
if( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat' ) && $slug == 'content' && $name == 'single-product' ){
$template = trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . 'woocommerce/' . $custom_template_name;
}
return $template;
}
```